# After multiple requests send to the server 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am working on the Django application where I want to create multiple asynchronous requests with ajax to django server. It works fine if there is less than 5 asynchronous requests but if there is more requests django `return 500 (Internal Server Error)` for some of the requests. If I make synchronous ajax requests it works fine.

Code where I send multiple ajax requests:

```
for (i=2; i <= lastIndex; i++){
    pidForm['page_index'] = i;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "search_by_pid" %}',
        data: pidForm,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(data.api_response.bugs).each(function(index, bugs){
                var id = bugs.id;
                createInnerHtml(id);
            });
        }
    })
}
```

My django view, where I send the ajax request:

```
def get_bug_by_pid(request):
    product_id_form = ProductIdForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'search_bug_by_pid.html',
                      {'page_title': 'ProductID', 'product_id_form': product_id_form})

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST['product_id']
        if 'page_index' in request.POST:
            api_call = ApiCall()
            page_index = request.POST['page_index']
            api_response = api_call.bug_api_call_by_pid(product_id, page_index)
            return JsonResponse({'api_response': api_response,'product_id': product_id})
```

```
Internal Server Error: /pid/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\views.py", line 26, in get_bug_by_pid
    api_response = api_call.bug_api_call_by_pid(product_id, page_index)
  File "api_calls.py", line 33, in bug_api_call_by_pid
    return json.loads(r.content)
  File "C:\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any idea how can I solve the problem or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what's the error trace? And is this on your local machine (i.e. using `runserver`) or on a production machine (i.e. nginx/apache + uwsgi/gunicorn)?

Comment: I currently using django development server on my local machine. @dirkgroten

Comment: I add it to my question. @dirkgroten

Comment: as you can see the error occurs at a line inside *api_calls.py* (line 33). Show us that code (or print `r`) to see why apparently`r.content` is `None`

Comment: It works fine if I send the requests synchronous, problem appears when I send more than 5 request asynchronous. I think that Django can not handle all the requests so some of them drop and django pass None in the api call.

Comment: `runserver` isn't WSGI. So yes, it's not going to cope well will multiple requests, but it won't just pass in wrong data somewhere midway the request, it'll drop connections (and your ajax would receive a timeout or dropped socket error). The error you have clearly shows a flaw in your code of api_calls.py because it's passing None to json.loads.

Comment: Also, since you're not showing us *api_calls.py* we can't say why there might be an issue there. If it's calling a remote API as the name suggests, maybe its the remote API that doesn't handle multiple calls well? In that case you're not properly handling the API response (`r`?) because it seems it can be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with your ajax request per-say. From the trace you provided, I can see that you are doing another API call to another service/url in your django view and your code is breaking there.

```
  File "api_calls.py", line 33, in bug_api_call_by_pid
    return json.loads(r.content)
```

By doing so many calls to the remote service, you *may* be either DDOSing that service, or the remote service is rate limiting you and not sending back valid JSON.

You can fix this fairly simply by either:

1. Check the response from the service before json encoding it to ensure that you are receiving valid JSON.

```
    if response.status_code == 200:

    return response.json()
```

2. Apply some of your own rate limiting in your service or set up channels(sockets) and stream the responses back asychronously, that way you can make each request synchronously.

I hope that this helps

Comment: It works fine if I send the requests synchronous, problem appears when I send more than 5 request asynchronous. I think that Django can not handle all the requests so some of them drop and django pass None in the api call.

Comment: Stop saying "it works fine". Your own code (*api_calls.py*) throws the error, so you're not error handling correctly. Yes, maybe multiple requests in fast sequence trigger the issue, but you can easily remedy that if you do proper error handling. You could return an error back to ajax and in your ajax it would be able to retry any request that failed.